# Python: True, False = False, True

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does Python's `True, False = False, True` do ?

I tried

```
True, False = False, True
print(1==1)
```

gives:

> True

and

```
True, False = False, True

print(1==2)
```

gives:

> False

Comment: This throws a SyntaxError in Python 3.

Comment: Hope you have a good reason for still using Python2

Answer (score 5):

So there are two (immutable) bool values.

One has a repr of `True` the other has a repr of `False`

As a convenience, Python2 has a couple of builtins that are references to those bool values.

You're just rebinding those builtin names to something else. `(1==1)` will still return the correct bool value for truth and it will render as `True`

Comment: Adding to the answer, bool is just a 0 or a 1 in the real sense and True and False are just stuff any language adds for our convenience